# R: Transforming (n*P) * N data frame into n * (N*P)

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, rbind, cbind

I'm using R and I have a data frame called `df` which has (n*P) rows and N columns.

```
         C1    C2 ... CN-1  CN
1-1     100    36 ...  136  76
1-2     120   -33 ...   87  42
1-3     150    14 ...  164  24
:
1-n      20    36 ...  136  76
2-1     109    26 ...  166  87
2-2     -33    87 ...   42  24
2-3     100    36 ...  136  76
:
2-n     100    36 ...  136  76
:
P-1     150    14 ...  164  24
P-2     100    36 ...  765  76
P-3     150    14 ...  164  94
:
P-n      10    26 ...  106  76
```

And I want to transform this data frame into a data frame with n rows and (N*P) columns. The new data frame, `df.new`, should look like

```
       C1-1  C2-1 ...   CN-1-1  CN-1  C1-2  C2-2  ...   CN-1-2   CN-2  ...  C1-P  C2-P ...   CN-1-P  CN-P
R1     100    36 ...      136    76    20    36  ...      136     76  ...  150    14  ...      164    24
R2     120   -33 ...       87    42   109    26  ...      166     87  ...  100    36  ...      765    76
:
:
Rn      20    36 ...      136    76   100    36  ...      136     76  ...   10    26   ...     106    76
```

That is to say, the first N columns of `df.new` are rbind of rows 1-1, 2-1, 3-1, ... , P-1 of `df`. The next N columns of `df.new` are rbind of rows 1-2, 2-2, 3-2, ... , P-2 of `df`. It follows till the last N columns of `df.new` which will be composed of rows rows 1-n, 2-n, 3-n, ... , P-n of `df`. (R1 of `df.new` is cbind of rows 1-1, 1-2,...,1-n. R2 of `df.new` is cbind of rows 2-1, 2-2,...,2-n. Rn of `df.new` is cbind of rows P-1, P-2,...,P-n.)

n, P and N are variables so the value of them depend on the case. I tried to create `df.new` using for loops but doesn't work well.

Here is my try which I kind of gave up.

```
  for (j in 1:n) {
    df.new <- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 1, dim(df)[2],
                           dimnames = list(c(), colnames(df))),
                    stringsAsFactors=F)

    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
      if (i %% n == 0) {
        df.new <- rbind(df.new, df[i,])
      } else if (i %% n == j) {
      df.new <- rbind(df.new, df[i,])
      }
    }
    assign(paste0("df.new", j), df.new)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

df %>%
  rownames_to_column("rowname") %>%
  separate(rowname, c("rowname_prefix", "rowname_suffix"), "-") %>%
  gather(col_name, value, -rowname_prefix, -rowname_suffix) %>%
  mutate(col_name = paste(col_name, rowname_prefix, sep="-")) %>%
  select(-rowname_prefix) %>%
  spread(col_name, value) %>%
  mutate(rowname_suffix = paste0("R", rowname_suffix)) %>%
  column_to_rownames("rowname_suffix")
```

**Output is:**

```
   C1-1 C1-2 C1-3 C2-1 C2-2 C2-3 C3-1 C3-2 C3-3 C4-1 C4-2 C4-3
R1  100  109  150   36   26   14  136  166  164   76   87   24
R2  120  -33  100  -33   87   36   87   42  765   42   24   76
R3  150  100  150   14   36   14  164  136  164   24   76   94
R4   20  100   10   36   36   26  136  136  106   76   76   76
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(C1 = c(100L, 120L, 150L, 20L, 109L, -33L, 100L, 
100L, 150L, 100L, 150L, 10L), C2 = c(36L, -33L, 14L, 36L, 26L, 
87L, 36L, 36L, 14L, 36L, 14L, 26L), C3 = c(136L, 87L, 164L, 136L, 
166L, 42L, 136L, 136L, 164L, 765L, 164L, 106L), C4 = c(76L, 42L, 
24L, 76L, 87L, 24L, 76L, 76L, 24L, 76L, 94L, 76L)), .Names = c("C1", 
"C2", "C3", "C4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1-1", 
"1-2", "1-3", "1-4", "2-1", "2-2", "2-3", "2-4", "3-1", "3-2", 
"3-3", "3-4"))
#     C1  C2  C3 C4
#1-1 100  36 136 76
#1-2 120 -33  87 42
#1-3 150  14 164 24
#1-4  20  36 136 76
#2-1 109  26 166 87
#2-2 -33  87  42 24
#2-3 100  36 136 76
#2-4 100  36 136 76
#3-1 150  14 164 24
#3-2 100  36 765 76
#3-3 150  14 164 94
#3-4  10  26 106 76
```